# Atomic/safe serving of single-use codes

Tags: php, python, mysql, amazon-web-services, sequence

I have a list of single-use discount codes for an ecommerce site I'm partnering with. I need to set up a page on my site where my users can fill out a form, and then will be given one of the codes. The codes are pre-determined and have been sent to me in a text file; I can't just generate them on the fly. I need to figure out the best way to get an unused code from the list, and then remove it from the list (or update a flag to mark it as used) at the same time, to avoid any possibility of giving two people the same code. In other words, something similar to a queue, where I can remove one item from the queue atomically.

This webapp will be running on AWS and the current code is Python (though I could potentially use something else if necessary; PHP would be easy). Ideally I'd use one of the AWS services or mysql to do this, but I'm open to other solutions if they're not a royal pain to get integrated. Since I thought "queue," SQS popped into my head, but this is clearly not what it's intended for (e.g. the 14 day limit on messages remaining in the queue will definitely not work for me). While I'm expecting very modest traffic (which means even really hacky solutions would probably work), I'd rather learn about the RIGHT way to do this even at scale.

Comment: I don't think you strictly need a queue here. It probably wouldn't cause problems if you gave each server a chunk of the code list and had them claim a refill whenever they ran low, though you'd need to handle the bit at the end when the list is out and some servers need to use codes already handed out to other servers. (Note: I am not an expert on cloud computing or your application.)

Comment: I'm confused by this. Even if I give each server its own list of codes, that server could have multiple requests come in at the same time (or at least close enough to the same time that one requests a code before the other has updated the db to say it's been used). Which really is the root of my problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this multithreaded? Multiprocessing? It's easy enough to coordinate within a single multithreaded server; you could use a [synchronized queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) of codes or a [counter](http://29a.ch/2009/2/20/atomic-get-and-increment-in-python) indexing into the code list. I have no idea what the best practices are, though.

Answer (score 0):

I cant give actual code examples, but one of the easiest ways to do it would just be an increment counter in the file, so something like

```
0
code1
code2
code3
etc
```

and just skipping that many lines every time a code is used.

You could also do this pretty simply in a database

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DynamoDB is a fast, NoSQL database from AWS, and it is potentially a good fit for this use case. Setting up a database table is easy, and you could load your codes into there. DynamoDB has a [DeleteItem operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html) that also allows you to retrieve the data within the same, atomic operation (by setting the `ReturnValues` parameter to `ALL_OLD`). This would allow you to get and delete a code in one shot, so no other requests/processes can get the same code. AWS publishes official SDKs to help you connect to and use their services, including both a Python and PHP SDK (see http://aws.amazon.com/tools/).